# Logical shift left and logical shift right over array

Tags: c, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I have an array of 64 bit integers to represent a bit vector. The index of individual bits are organized as follows:

`uint_64 BV[10]; // Bit vector of 10 * 64 bits
 bit indexing: 63 62 61 ... 2 1 0 | 127 126 125 ... 66 65 64 | ...`

I want to apply shift left and shift right operation on this bit vector. If I want to shift left by a factor of n where n < 64 (no. of bits per integer), I can just:

1. store the overflow msb from from BV[i] when BV[i] << n
2. shift left BV[i] by n
3. add the overflow msb from BV[i-1] to lsb of BV[i]
4. repeat this until the operation is completed.

In short add the overflow msb from previous index to the lsb of this index.

If shift factor n > 64, the overflow MSBs of BV[i] might land on different indexes of BV. What algorithm should I use to perform such operation efficiently? **Specially for n > 64.**

Note: It is implemented in C.

Comment: If n>64, start to "move" complete integer values by `n/64` positions. With the remaininging `n%64` bit positions, proceed as you already described.

Comment: Do you need to support shifts of more than 64 ?

Comment: Logical shift or rotate? Logical shift doesn't care about overflows. Except you can't shift negative numbers in C, nor can you left shift data into the sign bit of a signed integer. Right-shifting a negative integer also has poorly-defined behavior, because it can either do an arithmetic shift or a logical shift, depending on system. You need to use unsigned types for reliable bit shift.

Comment: @Lundin I cannot logical shift the whole array at once. So I have to shift index by index. If all the bits in the array are to be considered together, the overflow from index i should be add to the index i+1

Comment: So simply iterate over it, shift each item, store the overflow bits in the zero bytes of the previously shifted item. Should result in very efficient code.

Comment: One approach (depending on what you're planning to do with this data) would be to actually not shift anything and just keep a couple of pointers tracking what have you shifted so far. I.e. you would then access the appropriate "shifted" bit simply by taking these offsets into account.

Comment: @Groo I have other operations on the bit vector that considers the integer at any index as a whole. I think this offset approach very efficient but it will complicate the other operations.

Comment: @PrabhakarTayenjam: it depends on how often you're doing the shifting/reading, depending on the platform, it might be efficient to copy the bytes containing your integer into two variables and do two shifts. Alternatively, if you use a `char` array instead, you can quickly shift individual bytes (multiples of 8 bits) and then the remainder, which reduces the number of operations by ~8 or so on average. I believe keeping the shifting pointers would still be the fastest approach.